# Determining which line in an html table to manipulate with mechanize

Tags: python, regex, mechanize

I have a small script that uses mechanize to manipulate a webform. Here is a screenshot of the form (without the submit button at the bottom. Don't worry about that.)

[image: capture image]

The code:

```
import re
import mechanize

bs = mechanize.Browser()
server = raw_input("IP to retry: ")
bs.open("http://"+server+"/avicapture.html")
assert bs.viewing_html()
bs.select_form(name="avistatus_form")
form = bs.form
bs.find_control("AVI_STATUS_ACTION").items[1].selected=True
bs.find_control("avistatuscheck0").items[0].selected=True
bs.find_control("avistatuscheck1").items[0].selected=True
bs.find_control("avistatuscheck2").items[0].selected=True
bs.find_control("avistatuscheck3").items[0].selected=True
bs.find_control("avistatuscheck4").items[0].selected=True
bs.find_control("avistatuscheck5").items[0].selected=True
print "Sending retry signal."
bs.submit()
print server+" Retried!"
```

As it is, it will check all six boxes and submit the form with the dropdown option (AVI_STATUS_ACTION) as [1].

How do I go about having it determine which row (correlating to the proper avistatuscheck# control (checkbox)) is the most recent, and to only submit the form with that checkbox checked? As more files are transferred, they accumulate, and I don't need to resend them all. Just the most recent.

I know a little about regex; enough to use urllib2 to load an html page into a string and grab the percentage amount from the current 'In Progress' transfer, but I'm a bit lost on how to determine the most recent transfer corresponding to the correct control (checkbox.)

Comment: Can you include or link to an example file `avicapture.html`? The screenshot only hints how the actual structure would look like.

Comment: Absolutely. [avicapture.html](http://www.whatdoiknow.net/dump/avicapture.html)

Comment: That seems to be an incomplete dump. For one, the `<form ...` openening tag is missing.

Comment: I only dumped the portion that seemed relevant. Here is the [entire file](http://www.whatdoiknow.net/dump/avicapture_full.html)

Comment: Well, the whole document is not relevant, but the form is, at least for reproduction. Beware! The output you posted contains a password! Better that part and change the password.

Comment: Already did. Removed all relevant information shortly after posting. It's on an internal VPN inaccessible to the outside world, anyway. Thanks for the heads up though. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code contains the data in a nicer format than the actual HTML, in comment form:

```
</td>
<!--$FREETEXT|AVI_STATUS_START_TIME0||XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX$-->
<td>
2014/07/11 12:00:03      
</td>
<!--$FREETEXT|AVI_STATUS_END_TIME0||XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX$-->
<td>
2014/07/11 14:00:00      
</td>
<!--$FREETEXT|AVI_STATUS_FILE_SIZE0||XXXXXXXXXXXXX$-->
<td>
```

You can use a regular expression to parse this:

```
import re
import mechanize

bs = mechanize.Browser()
server = raw_input("IP to retry: ")

response = bs.open("http://" + server + "/avicapture.html")
assert bs.viewing_html()
bs.select_form(name="avistatus_form")

matches = re.findall(
    r'(?s)<!--\$FREETEXT\|AVI_STATUS_END_TIME([0-9]+).*?<td>\s*([0-9/]+ [0-9:]+)\s*\n',
    response.read())
latest_id, latest_time = max(matches, key=lambda m: m[1])
form = bs.form
bs.find_control("AVI_STATUS_ACTION").items[1].selected = True
bs.find_control("avistatuscheck" + latest_id).items[0].selected = True

print "Sending retry signal."
bs.submit()
print server+" Retried!"
```